# HTML hyperlinks in <main> element no longer clickable

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

Edit: all the links apart from those in the menu have stopped working. Has anyone come across anything like this before?

Original post:
For some reason that I cannot fathom, the links have stopped working on the img elements on [this web page](https://watership-down.com/books/) (check images of books). Each image should click through to the respective page. The links are there in the HTML so I think it might be a CSS problem. I tried changing the z-index and display but it didn't fix the problem.

Here's the HTML for the first book element:

```
<a href="/book/watership-gift/" class="more-info">
    <img class="book-cover" src="/assets/img/covers/wdg-cover.jpg">
</a>
```

Any ideas and advice welcome. Thank you.

Comment: There isn't anything in the HTML provided that would cause it to stop working. I would recommend checking out [mcve] as that will assist you in posting the best code to get the right answers

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I've just realised that all of the links have stopped working. I haven't come across a problem like this before so wanted to check if anyone had seen anything like this before.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mre]". Supply the absolute minimum code IN YOUR QUESTION that demonstrates the problem. Don't make people go to a link in order to help you, that discourages people from trying. Also, *when* that link breaks your question will be unusable for others searching for a similar solution.

Comment: As Riskbreaker said, remove the `z-index: -1` CSS style from the <main> tag, so your <a> will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this:

```
<main>
```

you have a css with:

```
z-index: -1;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. I didn't think to check the CSS on main, sorry!